# How to find a professional designer

Tags: logo, resource-recommendations

My friend needs a professional logo for his business but there are **so** many websites - I don't know where to start. Some are probably good and some are probably *horrible*. Can some experts in graphic design tell me some good websites to find people that can create a *very* professional logo for his business?

The top of his budget is around $200 to $300. This is for a digital copy logo that he will use on his website as well as other things like a sign for his business, etc.

Maybe a better way of asking this would be, "How do I find a professional designer when there are literally thousands of websites out there stating they are the best ones to choose when, more than likely not, that is not the case?"

Also, I totally realize that it's probably an insult to many by saying "I need a professional logo for $300 maximum" but that's the top of his budget, nothing I can do about that. He has already gotten the loan for the logo, so I'm trying to help him out as this would be overwhelming for him and he would probably end up regretting picking whomever he picked to design it for him. He could get lucky but it's more than likely that he wouldn't.

Comment: 99designs is a TERRIBLE place to get a logo from. It's the antithesis of professional.

Comment: @TroyWoo ah, yes, be VERY wary of that. The math will never work out in your favor, and you'll find that you don't usually get to do quality work. Some reading here: http://www.nospec.com/tag/99designs

Comment: As it stands I'm voting to close because I don't believe this is the correct website for this question. Instead you could edit the question to ask "What should I look for when hiring someone to design my logo?" And if that hasn't been answered would be a better question. Recommending businesses for you to hire is outside our scope though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want a professional logo, hire a professional designer.

Do *not* use one of the $99 logo web sites.

If you want a quality logo, you want to be able to work directly with a designer so that they can get a completely understanding of your business needs and objectives and then walk through the entire process with you.

You will not get that from one of those logo sites. Keep in mind the type of clients and, therefore, type of designers it attracts. It's focused on clients that value low-cost over everything. As such, the site is only attracting designers willing to work for extremely low pay. You do usually get what you pay for.

$300 won't get you a rock-star designer, but it will get you a better logo if you directly hire a designer and work one-on-one with them than if you spend it a place like 99designs.

Comment: So, where would be a good place to start looking for a professional designer? Maybe IRC #design channel? I may be the person that will be coding this site, not sure yet (this would be my FIRST website). But I am in NO WAY a good (or professional) designer so I would really like to find a talented designer to do this. Personally, I do realize that it's almost an insult to say I want a professional log for $300 as I understand how much work is involved in this. Still, that's his budget and I don't want to send him to one of those logo making websites, even though I'm tempted at this point. LOL

Comment: @CosmoCosmo word of mouth is ideal. Ping your professional network to see if anyone has a graphic designer to recommend. Otherwise, visit Behance or Dribbble and look for designers in your area with a portfolio that you feel fits the style you're looking for.

Comment: Again, thanks so much for the information. This does really help. I'm also starting to realize that if I intend on doing HTML/CSS for a living a better "professional network" is going to be needed, thanks for that tip and the comments...very helpful!

Answer (score 5):

Its important to understand that in essence your not actually buying just a logo. Sure, if thats what you pay for thats what you get. But ultimately, atleast if you want good impact, you should be buying a look and feel. You should also get instructions on how to apply that to your benefit, in different situations (Web, print etc... yes contracts still are on paper mostly). A good designer will be able to answer questions you dont even know exist yet.

This is why you often benefit greatly from a personal contact as the designer can far more easily determine your need. If you shop for cheap contract work be prepared to know all the details when making the contract.

Answer (score 2):

Along with all the other good answers here, please remember that you are creating a visual identity of a business that, ideally, makes money. This identity has the potential to be used for years to come. How valuable is the business to you or your friend? Surely it's more valuable than $99? If so, then invest well in the business identity. It's a crucial part of your business marketing and it can help establish your brand as one buyers can trust. I should also note that brand is more than just the visual identity - it's the promise and realization of everything a company, organization or even individual does.

Answer (score 0):

Are.na might be your best bet. Behance, the portfolio websites will earn you a good deal of amazing talented folks! Keep digging where designer are usually at. Twitter/Instagram— find some typography hashtags and you'll find a loooot of them there. Cheers! And rule of thumb— you get what you pay for