# How to set up a website to sell my own products?

Tags: designers, business, freelance

I'm an artist, and I want to run a website which can sell my prints of my art, where I can write blog posts, upload products, edit photos, manage customers, etc.

But I can't do all these things by myself alone. I need a team, at least a colleague who can handle the other work so that I can focus on creating more.

Where can I find those people? Where can I hire? Whom should I hire?

How do other freelancer artists and designers manage when they have so many things to do, and truly need some help?

Comment: I actually talked to the team leader of a starting mobile game company today, and he said that one of the more popular ways to find people (or be found in my case) is through Linkedin (specifically headhunters). I figure it's worth taking a look at.

Comment: Also relevant - [Where to hire a graphics designer for mobile app?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/57049/where-to-hire-a-graphics-designer-for-mobile-app) - [Where can I post a job listing to outsource a graphic design project?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5932/where-can-i-post-a-job-listing-to-outsource-a-graphic-design-project) - [How to find a professional designer](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/46250/how-to-find-a-professional-designer)

Comment: You can also search for marketing agencies that you like or are in your area and or post job listings. There are also a plethora of freelance websites. If you're a freelancer yourself, how do you get jobs?

Comment: thank you user 1337 and andrewH. I was curious that... there are so many things that should be cared, and how do other people handle it. Like... hiring every person for every different project..?

Comment: Thank you again! every advice means to me! cuz I'm a very newbie

Comment: This is the reason why companies exist. Some things just can not be done in small scale without funding. Simply you have to have some firends who can help you as a hobby, you need to come up with a business plan or you reduce scope so you can do it alone. In the end its not so much about what you want to do as what you can accomplish with your limited resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can always look around the web for a reputable source of virtual assistants. For example, using Upwork is an option. You will want to do your research before hand. Once in an agreement with a VA you are satisfied in working with, depending on how long you will work with them, you will want to make sure you have enough work to keep them busy. This can surprisingly be a challenge. https://www.upwork.com/o/jobs/browse/c/admin-support/sc/personal-virtual-assistant/

Comment: Are you affiliated with Upwork?

Comment: wow..thank you so so much!!!! I was stunned at the sentence "enough work to keep them busy" cuts tha'ts the part I was stuck too.. Thank you for your advice!!